# Get value of dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My ModelClass in

```
Public class Employee
{
    public SelectList PublishMonth { get; set; }
}
```

On view, it display as dropdown and working fine. Now on another partial view, i need to display all employee. I get List and i need to display value of PublishMonth for each employee. if i display like `<%=item.PublishMonth.SelectedValue%>`
it display ID instead of text. How can i get text?

Comment: My assingment is like oEmp.PublishMonth = new SelectList(pm, "PMid", "pmname", oAllEmployee[i].PMid); and view it is <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlmonth", Model.Employee[0].PublishMonth, new{ @class = "dropdownlist" } ) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public class Employe
{
  SelectList PublishedMonths {get;set;}
  int Month {get;set;}
}
```

in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Month, PublishedMonths) %>
```

Then when you post the form, the selected value will be binded in the Month property.

When you build your SelectList, I supposed you have something that sets the DisplayValue of the item.

I will suppose it is an extension method on an int

In the view I would do:

```
<%= Model.Month.GetDisplayValue() %>
```